# Using multiple GPUs in parallel on TensorFlow 2.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

This question is probably for those more experienced with TensorFlow.

I am using TensorFlow 2.12 and would like to use two GPUs in parallel for executing the same function with different parameters.

If I use the TensorFlow's default execution mode (eager execution), both GPUs are used, but not in parallel.

```
for gpu in ['GPU:0', 'GPU:1']:
    with tf.device(gpu):
        result = foobar(inputs ...)
        c.append(result)

resultSum = tf.add_n(c)
```

Executing the simple code above, GPU1 only starts processing when GPU0 finishes, which means that in practise I get no improvement from using two GPUs intead of one.

Disabling eager execution, i.e. using TensorFlow 1.X compatibility mode, I can achieve close to a 2x improvement of performance, which indicates that the two GPUs are being used at the same time.

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

for gpu in ['GPU:0', 'GPU:1']:
    with tf.device(gpu):
        result = foobar(inputs ...)
        c.append(result)

resultSum = tf.add_n(c)

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
resultSum_val = sess.run(resultSum)
```

Is there a way to achieve that behaviour without having to resort to TensorFlow 1.X compatibility mode?